# Using NLP to process leave absence requests

Tags: c#, .net, nlp

I'm developing an online leave management system. The plan is to integrate a Natural Language Processing (NLP) component such that the system can decide whether leave request should be accepted or not. For example:

If someone requests leave for a funeral, the system should give this request a high priority. If someone requests leave for a *family* funeral, it should get a higher priority relative to the previous funeral leave request. Conversely, if someone requests leave for a simple trip/holiday, the system should assign a lower priority relative to the other leave requests.

I'm using the `.net` framework and `C#` programming language. Could someone please suggest how I can:

- Integrate NLP to understand the leave requests and assign priority to each request
- Accept high priority leave requests and reject lower priority leave requests

Comment: It sounds like NLP is superfluous to what you're doing,  unless the entire goal of the project is to use NLP to do _something_ and you've chose leave management as the "something".

Comment: of cause yes John because project needs a research part for we have chosen NLP as research part

Comment: Can you define the high level criteria that you want to use to distinguish between high vs. low priority leave requests?

Comment: hi dmcer if someone requested leave for funeral so system give high priority for the request if someone requested family funeral so it'll get priority more that early one. if someone requested leave for trip system gives lower priority that both of other leaves. my idea goes like this..

Comment: Do you have access to a collection of existing leave requests along with their priority classifications?

Comment: of cause yes i have access to priority and all the leave information

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of choices:

1. If you have a lot of training cases, then you can extract words and their counts, and build a probabilistic naive bayes model to determine whether to accept or reject a request.
2. If you don't have any training cases, then you have to build a rule-based semantic system, which should be precise under experts' hands, but need a lot maintenance cost.